# Port Forward IPv6 to VM Hyper-v 2016

Tags: hyper-v, ipv6, windows-server-2016

Hey im stuck on how to forward port 80 and 443 over IPv6 to a VM in hyper-v 2016

I have my Hyper-v Host and this has a static IPv6 (2a02:29e0:1:136::/64) and IPv4 address on this I have Created a Windows Server 2016 VM this also has its own static IPv6 address (2a02:29e0:1:136::2) but no IPv4 address.

So on my VM i have IIS 10 running and I would like to port forward 80 and 443 over IPv6 so that users can access the websites hosted on there.

My network is setup as follows:

1 Ethernet card eth0 and connected to this is the Hyper-v Virtual Switch.There is no NAT in this network as its a dedicated server at seflow. I googled and found this command but it does not seem to work not sure why.

netsh interface portproxy add v6tov6 listenport=80 listenaddress=2102:29e0:1:136:: connectport=80 connect address=2102:29e0:1:136::2

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The entire point of IPv6 is that there are enough addresses to restore the IP end-to-end paradigm. That means that you do not need to forward ports (a NAT thing). With IPv6, you simply need to route correctly. Also, while you can assign the `2a02:29e0:1:136::` address to a host interface, the all-zeroes IPv6 address for a network is the reserved router anycast address.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the address assigned looks like will have to try contact seflow to check the routing. Did ask them this question but all i got was sorry we don't know what Hyper-v is :/